# How i can pass an extra parameter via the function used by the Array.forEach method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I've an Array :

```
var allchildsAr = new Array();
```

and i'm filling it with an object having a `parent` property(an object) and a `chlds` property which is an Array.

Here is the code to fill the array :

```
Ti.API.info("*****allchildsAr["+level+"] is null and "+elmn+" children will be added to it ");
allchildsAr[level] = new Array({parent:elmn,chlds:elmn.getChildren()});
```

and here is how i tried to display the array after the add :

```
  Ti.API.info("*****allchildsAr["+level+"] after add");
allchildsAr[level].forEach(logArrayJsonElements);
```

the `logArrayJsonElements` method is the following :

```
function logArrayElements(elemnt, indx, array) {
    Ti.API.info("*****Element at [" + indx + "]   : " + elemnt.id);
}

function logArrayJsonElements(elemnt, indx, array) {
    Ti.API.info("*****Element at [" + indx + "]   : " + elemnt.parent.id);
    elemnt.chlds.forEach(logArrayElements);
}
```

this works fine but what i want is to pass the parent element through `logArrayElements` so i can display it as a parent of the array's displayed element (and later to do another stuff with it..)

```
function logArrayElements(elemnt, indx, array, parent) {
    Ti.API.info("*****Element at [" + indx + "]   : " + elemnt.id+" child of :"+parent);
}
```

and now i'm confused because when the `logArrayElements` is called inside the `forEach` it doesn't take arguments and they are passed implicitly and if i add the `parent` as i did it be taken for another parameter(normally the `element` parameter) and anyway i'm not passing any of them so how i will get the `parent` inside the function and make the `foreach` pass it like other parameters ?

Comment: i thought i'm already on StackOverflow !! i didn't noticed that i'm in a wrong place..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by modifying your `forEach` line to:

```
function logArrayJsonElements(elemnt, indx, array) {
    Ti.API.info("*****Element at [" + indx + "]   : " + elemnt.parent.id);
    elemnt.chlds.forEach(function (element, index, arr) {
        logArrayElements(element, index, arr, elemnt.parent.id);
    });
}
```

Comment: i did something like that :)

Comment: function logArrayJsonElements(elemnt, indx, array) {
 
 var parentElm = "";
 
 function logArrayElements(elemnt, indx, array) {
 Ti.API.info("*****Element at [" + indx + "]   : " + elemnt.id+" child of :"+parentElm);
    }
 
 Ti.API.info("*****Element at [" + indx + "]   : " + elemnt.parent.id);
 parentElm = elemnt.parent.id;
 elemnt.chlds.forEach(logArrayElements);
}

Comment: but i wished i can pass the parent element implicitely like others, i think this can be done by overwitting a prototype

Comment: I think you can, using [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). Like so: `elemnt.chlds.forEach(logArrayElements.bind(this, {parent:elemnt.parent.id})`,(where the parent object acts as the preset leading argument) but you'll have to modify your logArrayElements function to `function logArrayElements(parent, elemnt, indx, array)`. This *should* work, try it and let me know

Answer (score 2):

Well, if `element` already has a `parent` property on it, then why not just use `element.parent` in `logArrayElements`?

Assuming that the elements are not of the same data structure, then `bind` also partially applies, so you could do this:

```
function logArrayElements(parent, element, index, array) {
    console.log("Element at [%s] : %s child of %s", index, element.id, parent);
}

function logArrayJsonElements(element, index, array) {
    element.chlds.forEach(logArrayElements.bind(null, element.parent));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Within `logArrayJsonElements` bind `logArrayElements` to an object with the  `parent` property set to `parent`

```
function logArrayJsonElements(elemnt, indx, array) {
    Ti.API.info("*****Element at [" + indx + "]   : " + elemnt.parent.id);
    elemnt.chlds.forEach(logArrayElements.bind({parent: elemnt.parent}));
}
```

`logArrayElements.bind({parent: elemnt.parent})` will return a new `Function` object whose context will be set to `{parent: elemnt.parent}` when it is invoked, allowing you to access the `parent` object using `this.parent`.

And modify `logArrayElements` to drop the `parent` parameter and use `this.parent` to access the parent object:

```
function logArrayElements(elemnt, indx, array) {
    Ti.API.info("*****Element at [" + indx + "]   : " + elemnt.id+" child of :" this.parent);
}
```